# parsing json with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

So I have a json object

```
var json = {"School":{"Keywords":"HBS","SchoolName":"","SchoolUrl":"/Careers/Apply/University_recruiting/Schools/HBS.aspx"}, "School":{"Keywords":"Stanford","SchoolName":"","SchoolUrl":"/Careers/Apply/University_recruiting/Schools/Stanford.aspx"}}
```

And I want to loop through it to find all of the keywords in this object.
I've tried `$(json.School).each(function(){ console.log(this.Keywords) }` but it doesn't seem to work. Any clues?

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON object.

Comment: I don't think that's valid JSON; it has duplicate keys in an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.each` is used with arrays. What you have is not an array. It is a simple javascript object with properties. Here's how an array would look like in javascript:

```
var json = [
    {
        "Keywords":"HBS",
        "SchoolName":"",
        "SchoolUrl":"/Careers/Apply/University_recruiting/Schools/HBS.aspx"
    }, 
    {
        "Keywords":"Stanford",
        "SchoolName":"",
        "SchoolUrl":"/Careers/Apply/University_recruiting/Schools/Stanford.aspx"
    }
];
```

Now you can loop:

```
$.each(json, function() {
    console.log(this.Keywords);
});
```

And here's a [working live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V3jKG/).

Comment: Hmm, no it wouldn't. There's no keys in an array.

Comment: @passcod, you are correct. I've updated my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: he's talking about "School". i think that would just error out. also, $.each works on objects, it iterates through all the properties and their values. $.each({a: 1, b: 2}, function (key, value) { // first iteration key = 'a', value = 1});

Comment: right I tried this example but still didn't work... maybe the format of the json string is incorrect?

Comment: @climboid, did you see my updated example. Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V3jKG/

Comment: @darin: do you sleep sometime? or you share this account with someone lol

Answer (score 1):

Your json object is a nested dictionary array. Reference its elements with strings, like this:

```
$.each(json['School'], function() {...
```

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions. You have asked three, and all of them are still open.

Answer (score 0):

You should use for...in

```
for (key in json){
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert(json[key]);
    }
}
```

always check if the properties is of the object to avoid properties inherited from the prototype

EDIT - that is way to iterate over properties of the object, but i don't know if yours is a valid object

Answer (score 0):

First, json is a terrible variable name. The JSON there is invalid. The first { should be a [, and the last } should be an ]. You should probably just ditch that redundant "School" property as well.

Fixing that:

```
var schoolArray = [
    {"Keywords":"HBS","SchoolName":"","SchoolUrl":"/Careers/Apply/University_recruiting/Schools/HBS.aspx"},
    {"Keywords":"Stanford","SchoolName":"","SchoolUrl":"/Careers/Apply/University_recruiting/Schools/Stanford.aspx"}];

$.each(schoolArray, function(key, value)
{
    var keywords = value.Keywords;
    var schoolName = value.SchoolName;
});
```